# Debug and production resources

Tags: android, debugging, android-resources

Some Android libraries such as [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/#analytics-xml) use resources for configuration purposes (e.g. `ga_trackingId`).

In these cases, I have different values for debug and production. What I currently do is manually comment the production values when I'm debugging, and viceversa. It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!--  DEBUG -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-12345678-1</string>
    <integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">1</integer>
    <bool name="ga_debug">true</bool>

    <!--  PRODUCTION -->    
    <!--string name="ga_trackingId">UA-87654321-1</string>
    <integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">120</integer>
    <bool name="ga_debug">false</bool-->
</resources>
```

This way of switching configuration is tedious and error-prone, and generates unnecessary repository changes if I'm not careful. Is there a better way?

(e.g.: on iOS I use conditional compilation with the `IF DEBUG` macro)

Comment: Something like `res/values-debug` would be awesome.

Answer (score 19):

Under the `src` folder you probably have a `main` folder where you store all shared stuff. But you can have specific resources for flavours or build types.

Put a folder named `debug` under the `src` folder where you will place a copy of your xml file but with with proper content. You have to maintain the folder structure under `debug` so the `global_tracker.xml` needs to be placed in `../src/debug/res/xml`

Your folder structure should look like this:

[image]

Android Studio will notice that this xml file have multiple versions.

This is what you should see in AS:

[image]

You can use this for all kind of resources, i.e., have multiple versions of the same file and it will be "magically" chosen properly.

Comment: This is the proper answer.

Comment: Android Studio sees the resources for debug, but how do you access them from the code?

Comment: @JohnGlen once you retrieve the resource in your code. It will contain the respective value loaded in memory depending on which environment you are running, production, debug, and so on.

Comment: It must have been some out of date code, because a rebuild fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Google Maps keys where they depend on the signature. What I did was to use the ant script which generates/copies resources to the project conditionally. You can include the ant script in Eclipse under the Project>Properties>Builders

If you need to use the DEBUG value in the code, you can create a java file with static values that will be included conditionally too.

Please comment if ant environment variables worked properly (you can see the "Build type: " message in console after execution of the script).

```
<project name="build-res">
<property name="conditional.resources.dir" value="myresources" />
<property name="keys_file" value="res/values/keys.xml" />

<target name="copy-release" if="${build.mode.release}" >
    <property name="build.type" value="Release" />
    <echo message="Build type: ${build.type}" />
    <property name="google.maps.key" value="nanana-value-for-release" />
    <copy file="${conditional.resources.dir}/Release.java" tofile="gen/com/example/project/BuildInfo.java" />
</target>

<target name="copy-debug" if="${build.mode.debug}">
    <property name="build.type" value="Debug" />
    <echo message="Build type: ${build.type}" />
    <property name="google.maps.key" value="lalala-value-for-debug" />
    <copy file="${conditional.resources.dir}/Debug.java" tofile="gen/com/example/project/BuildInfo.java" />
</target>

<target name="build-res" depends="copy-debug,copy-release">
    <echo file="${keys_file}" message="&lt;?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?&gt;&lt;resources&gt;&lt;string name='google_maps_key'&gt;${google.maps.key}&lt;/string&gt;&lt;/resources&gt;" />
</target>
</project>
```